# Page resets after an event fire in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, file-upload

So I've been having an issue lately that when I try to upload a file in firefox, it gets reset. I've tested this feature out in Chrome and it works perfectly, but it doesn't work in firefox. Looking at firebug console log gave me no clues as to where it resets. I am using the [resumable.js](https://github.com/23/resumable.js) JS library to chunk my uploads with a PHP backend. This works 100% in Chrome.

This happens when I click on the upload button which calls the `resume.upload()` method, and as soon as it does, it resets the frame so the upload doesn't go through.
If i add a breakpoint at where this method is called, and let it execute by stepping over it once, it works fine, but if I let it go, it just resets

Small snippets of JS and HTML:

```
<form>
<input id="showBrowse" style="margin-right:5px;" type="file">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button id="uploadFileBTN" style="margin-left:25px" onclick='resume.upload()'>Start Upload</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<br>
<span style="margin-right:3px;margin-right:10px;" id="pauseOrplay"></span><img id='pauseDL' onclick='resume.pause();paused();' alt="Pause">
<span style="margin-left:23px;margin-right:10px;" id="cancelTXT"></span><img id='cancelDL' onclick='resume.cancel();cancel();' alt="Cancel">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="overwriteFile" onclick='overwriteIt()'>Overwrite if file already exists <br>
<input type="hidden" value="<%=view.getUID()%>" id="hiddenUID">
</form>
```

And here is the JS implementation

```
/**
 * Resumable.js implementation
 */
$("#stitchLabel").hide();
resume = new Resumable({
    target:uploadURL,
    query:{rewrite: $("#overwriteFile").attr('checked')?true:false},
    resumableChunkSize:1*1024*1024,
    simultaneousUploads:1,
    testChunks:false
});
if(!resume.support){
    hidePauseAndCancel();
    $("#showBrowse").hide();
    $("#uploadFileBTN").hide();
    alert("Sorry! The upload file feature is not supported on your browser. Please use Firefox 4+, Chrome 11+, or Safari 6+");
}
resume.assignBrowse(document.getElementById("showBrowse"));

resume.on('fileAdded',function(file){
    var idFile = file.uniqueIdentifier;
    $("#fileBlock").append("<li id='"+file.uniqueIdentifier+"'>"+file.fileName+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id='fileProgress'><b>Waiting for upload to start</b></span></li>");
    $("#uploadFileBTN").attr('disabled',false);
    $("#overwriteFile").attr('disabled',true);
    $("#pauseDL").hide();
    $("#resumeDL").hide();
    $("#pauseOrplay").hide();

});

resume.on('fileSuccess',function(file, message){
    alert("finished");
    var name = file.fileName;
    $("#fileBlock").find("#"+file.uniqueIdentifier).remove();
    $("#userFiles").children().find("img#pauseDL").remove();
    $("#userFiles").children().find("img#resumeDL").remove();
    $("#fileBlock").children().find("#"+file.uniqueIdentifier).css('color',"#D4D4D4");
    $("#fileBlock").find("#wait").show();
    hidePauseAndCancel();
    if(($("#fileBlock").find("#wait")).length == 0){
        $("#fileBlock").append("<b id='wait'>Stitching... don't press cancel</b>");
    }

});
resume.on('fileProgress', function(file){
    if(resume.progress()*100>0){
        $("#pauseDL").attr('src','/img/IMGS/icons/pause.png').show();
        $("#pauseOrplay").html("<b>Pause</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
        $("#pauseOrplay").show();
        $("#cancelTXT").html("<b>Cancel</b>");
    }
    $("#cancelDL").attr('src','/img/IMGS/icons/delete-icon.png').show();
    $("#cancelTXT").html("<b>Cancel</b>");
    $("#cancelTXT").show();
    $("#uploadFileBTN").attr('disabled',true);
    $("#fileBlock").find("#"+file.uniqueIdentifier).find("#fileProgress").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>"+Math.floor(file.progress()*100)+"%</b>").css('color','#05AD24');
    $("#overwriteFile").attr('disabled',true);
});
```

Firebug gives no messages at all. Is there something I'm using that's not supported in FF? FF v20 by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems as though firefox doesn't like

```
<button></button>
```

and prefers

```
<input type="button">
```

As soon as I changed that, the onclick event fired normally.